# python 'x days ago' to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have strings that show a date in the following format:

```
x minutes/hours/days/months/years ago
```

I need to parse that to a datetime using python.

It seems dateutil can't do it.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It looks like `dateutil` can handle it in the format that Lattyware and I prescribed, just substituting `dateutil.relativedelta` for `datetime.timedelta`.  (see my update and link).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure you can do it.  You just need a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
s = "3 days ago"
parsed_s = [s.split()[:2]]
time_dict = dict((fmt,float(amount)) for amount,fmt in parsed_s)
dt = datetime.timedelta(**time_dict)
past_time = datetime.datetime.now() - dt
```

As an aside, it looks like [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) has a `relativedelta` which acts like a timedelta, but the constructor also accepts `months` and `years` in the arguments (and apparently the arguments need to be integers).

Comment: relativedelta works better, it doesn't work with a float though, it needs `amount` to be an int.

Comment: @chaft -- Thanks.  I suppose that makes sense.  While it's concievable that you can come up with a definition for 3 months ago, it's probably not concievable to say 3.5 months ago and have a unique date.

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way is to use [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/)

```
import dateparser
date_ago = '4 months ago'
date     = dateparser.parse(date_ago)
date     = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Output:

```
'2020-01-08'
```

---

you may need install `dateparser` pip package

```
pip install dateparser
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Also, I didn't run into any issues with the negative timestamp.

Comment: This indeed is easier than the timedelta suggested by other users

Answer (score 11):

Since your arguments are something like 2 days ago, 3 months ago, 2 years ago. The function below could be of help in getting the exact date for the arguments. You first need to import the following date utils

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

Then implement the function below

```
def get_past_date(str_days_ago):
    TODAY = datetime.date.today()
    splitted = str_days_ago.split()
    if len(splitted) == 1 and splitted[0].lower() == 'today':
        return str(TODAY.isoformat())
    elif len(splitted) == 1 and splitted[0].lower() == 'yesterday':
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(days=1)
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['hour', 'hours', 'hr', 'hrs', 'h']:
        date = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(hours=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.date().isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['day', 'days', 'd']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(days=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['wk', 'wks', 'week', 'weeks', 'w']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(weeks=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['mon', 'mons', 'month', 'months', 'm']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(months=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['yrs', 'yr', 'years', 'year', 'y']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(years=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    else:
        return "Wrong Argument format"
```

You can then call the function like this:

```
print get_past_date('5 hours ago')
print get_past_date('yesterday')
print get_past_date('3 days ago')
print get_past_date('4 months ago')
print get_past_date('2 years ago')
print get_past_date('today')
```

Answer (score 9):

This can be done easily with [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)s:

```
import datetime

def string_to_delta(string_delta):
    value, unit, _ = string_delta.split()
    return datetime.timedelta(**{unit: float(value)})
```

Producing:

```
>>> string_to_delta("20 hours ago")
datetime.timedelta(0, 72000)
```

Although this will require some extra work to deal with months/years - as adding a month to a date is an ambiguous operation, but it should be a simple addition if you know what you want it to mean.

To get an actual time, simply take the delta away from [`datetime.datetime.now()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

Comment: Your splitting is a bit more elegant than mine.  +1.  (although I would use `float(n)` -- timedelta seems to handle it OK and it would allow use of `3.5 days ago`.).

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks for the suggestion - didn't know ``timedelta``s handled floats.

Comment: @chaft Afraid not - ``timedelta``s don't handle months or years as it's relatively ambiguous as to what adding a month to a date means. You will need to handle those as a special case.

Comment: Thanks, it works for minutes hours and days but fails on months and years.

Comment: As I said, what does adding a month mean? Going to the same date on the next month? If so, what if you are on a day that isn't in the next month? If you are happy with four weeks as a month, then you can just convert a month to that (and a year by extension).

Comment: @Lattyware Even without months and years this is great. Thanks. I'll take care of the months and years manually.

Comment: FYI, this will not handle singular units, like `1 day ago`

Comment: @Renaud You could add special case handling to deal with the singular, although that that point you'd probably want to start using a real parser rather than relying on something a little hack-y like this.

Answer (score 1):

completely exaggerated solution but I needed something more flexible:

```
def string_to_delta(relative):
    #using simplistic year (no leap months are 30 days long.
    #WARNING: 12 months != 1 year
    unit_mapping = [('mic', 'microseconds', 1),
                    ('millis', 'microseconds', 1000),
                    ('sec', 'seconds', 1),
                    ('day', 'days', 1),
                    ('week', 'days', 7),
                    ('mon', 'days', 30),
                    ('year', 'days', 365)]
    try:
        tokens = relative.lower().split(' ')
        past = False
        if tokens[-1] == 'ago':
            past = True
            tokens =  tokens[:-1]
        elif tokens[0] == 'in':
            tokens = tokens[1:]


        units = dict(days = 0, seconds = 0, microseconds = 0)
        #we should always get pairs, if not we let this die and throw an exception
        while len(tokens) > 0:
            value = tokens.pop(0)
            if value == 'and':    #just skip this token
                continue
            else:
                value = float(value)

            unit = tokens.pop(0)
            for match, time_unit, time_constant in unit_mapping:
                if unit.startswith(match):
                    units[time_unit] += value * time_constant
        return datetime.timedelta(**units), past

    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError("Don't know how to parse %s: %s" % (relative, e))
```

This can parse things like:

- `2 days ago`
- `in 60 seconds`
- `2 DAY and 4 Secs`
- `in 1 year, 1 Month, 2 days and 4 MICRO`
- `2 Weeks 4 secs ago`
- `7 millis ago`

A huge *but*: It simplifies month and year to 30 and 365 days respectively. Not always what you want, though it's enough for some cases.

Answer (score 1):

@mgilson answer didn't work for me where **dateutil.relativedelta** did the job:

*Edited following @mosc9575 advise*

```py
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

time_ago = "1 month ago"
val, unit = time_ago.split()[:2]
past_time = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(**{unit:int(val)})
```

Comment: This works fine but I think your if statement is unnecessary (as far as I was testing). Maybe you can edit this to a function like Gareth Latty did.

Comment: That's correct! I didn't realise relativedelta accept both argument month=3 & months=3

Answer (score 0):

Custom function to convert `x hours ago` to `datetime`, `x hour, y mins ago` to `datetime`, etc in Python.

Function takes single parameter of type string which is parsed using RegExp. RegExp can be customized to match function input.

For usage see examples below.

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def convert_datetime(datetime_ago):
    matches = re.search(r"(\d+ weeks?,? )?(\d+ days?,? )?(\d+ hours?,? )?(\d+ mins?,? )?(\d+ secs? )?ago", datetime_ago)

    if not matches:
        return None

    date_pieces = {'week': 0, 'day': 0, 'hour': 0, 'min': 0, 'sec': 0}

    for i in range(1, len(date_pieces) + 1):
        if matches.group(i):
            value_unit = matches.group(i).rstrip(', ')
            if len(value_unit.split()) == 2:
                value, unit = value_unit.split()
                date_pieces[unit.rstrip('s')] = int(value)

    d = datetime.today() - timedelta(
        weeks=date_pieces['week'],
        days=date_pieces['day'],
        hours=date_pieces['hour'],
        minutes=date_pieces['min'],
        seconds=date_pieces['sec']
    )

    return d
```

Example usage:

```py
dates = [
    '1 week, 6 days, 11 hours, 20 mins, 13 secs ago',
    '1 week, 10 hours ago',
    '1 week, 1 day ago',
    '6 days, 11 hours, 20 mins ago',
    '1 hour ago',
    '11 hours, 20 mins ago',
    '20 mins 10 secs ago',
    '10 secs ago',
    '1 sec ago',
]    

for date in dates:
    print(convert_datetime(date))
```

Output:

```sh
2019-05-10 06:26:40.937027
2019-05-16 07:46:53.937027
2019-05-15 17:46:53.937027
2019-05-17 06:26:53.937027
2019-05-23 16:46:53.937027
2019-05-23 06:26:53.937027
2019-05-23 17:26:43.937027
2019-05-23 17:46:43.937027
2019-05-23 17:46:52.937027
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to install dependencies using pip3

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import re

baseDate = date.today() #date(2020, 4, 29)

hoursPattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d?\d?) hours? ago')
daysPattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d?\d?) days? ago')
weeksPattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d?\d?) weeks? ago')
monthsPattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d?\d?) months? ago')
yearsPattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d?\d?) years? ago')


days = 0
daysMatch = daysPattern.search(ago)
if daysMatch:
    days += int(daysMatch.group(1))

hours = 0
hoursMatch = hoursPattern.search(ago)
if hoursMatch:
    hours += int(hoursMatch.group(1))

weeks = 0
weeksMatch = weeksPattern.search(ago)
if weeksMatch:
    weeks += int(weeksMatch.group(1))

months = 0
monthsMatch = monthsPattern.search(ago)
if monthsMatch:
    months += int(monthsMatch.group(1))

years = 0
yearsMatch = yearsPattern.search(ago)
if yearsMatch:
    years += int(yearsMatch.group(1))

yourDate = baseDate - relativedelta(hours=hours, days=days, weeks=weeks, months=months, years=years)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance for **datetime** to work with other languages (italian) '*x-days ago to date*'?

```
import locale\
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'it_IT.UTF-8')
```

doesn't make any difference.