# Parse english textual date expression into datetime

Tags: python

How do I convert these strings:

```
one hour ago
three days ago
two weeks ago
yesterday
next month
```

into Python datetime object?

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340963/natural-language-time-parser

Comment: Maybe do some research and incorporate it into your question.

Comment: Jon Clements: thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [parsedatetime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/1.1.2) for parsing human readable date/time text from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340963/natural-language-time-parser) provided by Jon Clements. Here is a solution in case you interested:

```
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime as pdt

time_str = '1 hour ago'
cal = pdt.Calendar()
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(cal.parse(time_str)[0]))
time_formatted = dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y %H:%M')
print(time_formatted) # will print something like: Dec 15, 2013 02:10
```

Also see this question: [python 'x days ago' to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12566152/1396314)